# Is there a way to check if record exist and autoincrement if it it in php

Tags: php

So i have a database which has contact_name and also referenc_no.

So when i save a fresh contact into the database it auto assigns the reference number by taking the first 4 letters from the name and add 001 to the back.

```
$name = 'John Doe';
$number = 1;
$justname = explode('  ',  $name);
$firstname = $justname[0];
$reference_no = strtoupper(substr($firstname, 0, 4)) . str_pad($number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

E.G Contact name is John Doe so reference number is JOHN001.

But i want to know how i can write a code that checks if the name John exists in the database and add 002 to it and also 003 if another user with the name John exists.

The below code checks if the any record has the name `John` in it and adds 002 behind it

```
$jah = $contact_name;
$just = App::sql()->query_row("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE contact_name = '$jah'" );
$final = explode('  ', $jah);
$justfinal = $final[0];
```

```
        if($justfinal == $firstname){
            $name = explode(' ', $contact_name);
            $majorname = $name[0];
            $ref = 1;
            $ref++;
            $reference_no = strtoupper(substr($majorname, 0,4)). str_pad($ref, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
```

The above code checks and adds 002 but if another record with john exists it does not add 003 it adds 002

Comment: _"The above code checks and adds 002 but if another record with john exists it does not add 003 it adds 002"_ - if all you do is `$ref = 1; $ref++;` each time, then you must not wonder much about the result you are getting. `$ref` should be the highest such value you _read_ from your database at this point, instead of getting initialized statically with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Reference_no is also available in the database, right?

So, why not check the number of existing references that way?

```php
$row = App::sql()->query_row("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer WHERE reference_no LIKE '" . strtoupper(substr($firstname,0,4)) . "%'");
```

Now just add 1 to the number of already existing references, and generate the new reference:

```php
$number = $row[0] + 1;
$new_reference_no = strtoupper(substr($firstname,0,4)) . str_pad($number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Yes referenc_no exists what your code does is to increase the first element which works, what if there is another element. E.g 1. JOHN001, JOHN002, JOHN003

Comment: @HenryOladeji My code *counts* the number of occurrences of `JOHN###` already existing in the database. If there exists 3 records for John, my code generates `JOHN004` for the new entry.

Comment: the $row[0] gets the first occurrence all the time and just add 1 to it.

Comment: @HenryOladeji Note the `COUNT(*)` in the query. It doesn't return the first row of your database table, it returns the **total number** of existing occurrences of `reference_no` starting with `JOHN`. Then adds 1 to that number for the new reference.